# Fetching multiple levels of related records in Entity Framework .NET5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have the following code. It brings back the **Show** and its related **Slides**. However **Slide** also has related **Items** but I have no idea how to make the query include those (There is a foreign key in the db).

```
Show sh = (from s in _context.Shows
           where s.ShowId == id
           select new Show()
           {
               ShowId=s.ShowId,
               ShowName=s.ShowName,
               Slides=s.Slides           
           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I modify this to make it also fetch the list of **Items** for each **Slide**?

I am using .Net5

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using LINQ for the whole query?

Comment: Yes, I do not like it. Linq Query Syntax is entirely valid code and in many cases looks nicer in my mind. This Query could get quite complex. It just looks simple right now.

Comment: @CompiledIO What is not LINQ in this query? Query syntax is also LINQ, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you defined your DbContext correctly the LINQ would be

```
Show sh = _context.Shows
    .Where(s => s.ShowId == id)
    .Include(s => s.Slides)
    .ThenInclude(sl => sl.Items)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This works thanks. Just to complete the Answer. In Query Syntax the code is Show sh = (from s in _context.Shows
                       where s.ShowId == id
                       select s).Include(x=>x.Slides).ThenInclude(x=>x.Panes).FirstOrDefault();